# Request a router to search for a wifi network

Tags: networking, router, unix, snmp

My computer is connected to a router by Ethernet and doesn't have wifi. The router has a wifi interface.

I would like to find a way to interrogate the router, in a script, to know if a wifi network with a given SSID exists. I don't know where to start or if it's possible.

What protocol should I use for that purpose ? Can I achieve that with smnp ? How can I request a router to search for a given wifi network ?

Comment: If your router supports SNMP, try doing an SNMPwalk on it, and see what OIDs it returns.  You may have to install vendor-provided MIBs to get the textual interpretations of the OIDs.
From the output of a walk, you might be able to figure out what SNMPget query, if any, might tell you what other SSIDs are being broadcast.

Comment: There really aren't any standard protocols for what you're asking. If you happen to be able to do it via SNMP, you'll be very lucky. You might want to consider running Linux on your router if one of the Linux router distributions such as OpenWrt supports your router. Then you might be able to write a script to SSH into your router and use the Linux command-line tools to get the information you want.